# Proguard causing SherlockMapActivity to lose access to MapActivity

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock, google-maps-android-api-2, proguard

I'm getting the following console warnings from Proguard during package export:

> Warning: com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockMapActivity: can't find
> superclass or interface com.google.android.maps.MapActivity
>
> Warning: com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockMapActivity: can't find
> referenced class com.google.android.maps.MapActivity

Using `-dontwarn com.google.android.maps.MapActivity` results in app crash ([retraced stack trace](http://pastebin.com/nkp2MHKd))

I'm using a standard up-to-date proguard-android.txt and I've added the following to my proguard-project.txt (in addition to the rules specified by Google Play )to try and resolve (a bit redundant perhaps but I'm trying not to miss anything):

```
-keep class * extends com.google.android.maps.MapActivity 
-keep class com.google.android.maps**
-keep class com.google.android.maps.*
-keep class com.google.android.maps.MapActivity
```

Still new to Proguard, am I missing something obvious here?